# How to distinct populated collections with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 collections and i want to get distinct subject(chapter) in selected book

```
Books={title:string, Chaps:Chapters, date:date}
Chapters= {title:string, subject:string}
```

How to use

```
books.find(id:"5455545").populate('Chaps').distinct('Chaps.subject').exec(function (er,data){
    console.log(data)
    })

// i got this result => [] empty array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use that directly with mongoDB. Use an external filter.

Comment: which kind of filter !!

Comment: You cant use distinct with populate, so you should make your own filter.